# Варианты записи java

Tags: java, база-данных

Есть desktop приложение на java, делаю функцию сохранения. Смысл её будет сохранять n-e количество массивов, а после считывать их. Есть банальный вариант записывать их в текст файл. Но как понимаю, это не самый лучший способ. Знаю что в теории это можно сделать через БД. Стоит ли пытаться делать это через БД? Если кто знает другие способы буду благодарен за подсказку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете сохранить их просто файл

- текстовый

  - xml
  - json
  - yaml
- бинарный, используя сериализацию (ObjectOutputStream)

Использовать БД имеет смысл, если вы собираетесь делать к ней более сложные запросы. Для простого сохранения и восстановления я бы использовал файлы.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.

Хранить данные в БД - это удобная и хорошая практика. Если Вы планируете развиваться в написании приложений, то почти везде у Вас будет потребность использовать БД. В этом случае Вам действительно, возможно, стоит попрактиковаться в работе с базами данных и освоить это дело, даже на примере Вашей текущей задачи.

Самым простым вариантом для начала может быть база данных H2. Это простая файловая база данных, она не требует разворачивания как MySQL, Postgres,...

Кроме того, БД может дать Вам мощные инструменты в виде sql-запросов, если в дальнейшем понадобится запрашивать различные выборки Ваших данных, производить фильтрацию, собирать статистику, производить анализ данных и т.д.